# ejs array in an object

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Here is the code in nodejs(express):

```
      response.redirect('file',{test: [{name:'sarah',arr:[1,2,3]},{name:'beck',arr: [2,3,4]}]
```

Now I want to access the 'arr' for every name in the array of objects.In ejs file:

```
      <% test.forEach(index,item){ %>
       <p><%= item.arr %></p>
       <% }) %>
```

This is printed as 1,2,3 and 2,3,4 but I want the answer to be [1,2,3] and [2,3,4].Can someone help?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(item.arr)`?

Comment: Is it like this <p> <%= JSON.stringify(item.arr) %></p> ?? @Ifaruki

Comment: It is getting displayed as `[]` .There are no elements in it @Ifaruki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for .. of` loop to iterate over all entries of `test` and then use `JSON.stringify` on the entries' `arr` property:

```
<% for(const testData of test){ %>
<%= JSON.stringify(testData.arr) %>
<% } %>
```